# What is the infimum and supremum from $K=\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\}\}$ for the partial order $\subseteq$ of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the infimum and supremum from $K=\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\}\}$ for the partial order $\subseteq$ of  $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$
I don't know how to determine this.. Hope somebody can help me to understand it.

Comment: In general, for any set $X$, and any family $\{ S_{i} : i \in I \}$ of subsets of $X$, if we partially order $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by inclusion, then $\inf \{ S_{i} : i \in I \} = \cap_{i \in I} S_{i}, \sup \{ S_{i} : i \in I \} = \cup_{i \in I} S_{i}$. The argument is the same as that given by Henno Brandsma.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if we have two elements $A$, $B$ (so subsets of the natural numbers) in the partial order $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq)$, then $A \cap B$ is their infimum, and $A \cup B$ is their supremum.

Clearly $A \cap B \subseteq A, B$, so it is a lower bound, and if $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$ then $C \subseteq A \cap B$ as well, so it is the largest lower bound.

A dual argument holds for the union.

Comment: Neither the intersection, not the union belongs to $K$; the OP wants the supremum and the infimum *from $K$*.

Comment: @AlexM. I don't think so. Although OP said "for $K =...$, he also said, not just "for $\subseteq$", but specifically "for $\subseteq$ from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$".

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

Neither $\{ 0, 1 \} \subseteq \{ 0, 2 \}$ or $\{ 0, 2 \} \subseteq \{ 0, 1 \}$ is true so no member of $K$ is itself the sup or inf.

However

$$\{ 0 \} \subseteq \{ 0, 1 \} \quad\text{ and }\quad \{ 0 \} \subseteq \{ 0, 2 \}$$

also

$$\{ 0 , 1\} \subseteq \{ 0, 1, 2\} \quad\text{ and }\quad \{ 0 , 2\} \subseteq \{ 0, 1, 2\}$$

Now show that these lower and upper bounds are the inf and sup respectively.

Comment: I thought the set $K \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and from that subset $K$ i need the sup and inf.

Comment: What has this to do with whether or not inf and sup exist? Wouldn't it make sense to say that $\{0\}$ and $\{0,1,2\}$ are respectively the inf and sup? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The question asked for infimum and supremum (greatest lower and least upper bounds), not maximum and minimum. Those certainly do exist, since a power set is a lattice.

Comment: Yes, apologies, my original answer was wrong. Hopefully now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The set $K$ contains *no* supremum and *no* infimum. Are you sure that the statement of the problem is correct?

The infimum would have to be a subset from $K$ contained in both those sets, so the only possibilities are $\emptyset$ or $\{ 0 \}$, but neither of these belongs to $K$.

Similarly, the supremum would be the smallest set from $K$ containing the two sets from $K$, but there is no such set in $K$.

Comment: Our professor gave us this exercise, so I think it's right..

Comment: @fragant: There is nothing *wrong* with it, it just is a little weird and very simple. Please note that one of the answers that were here got deleted. Henno's answer (which essentially says the same as the deleted one) is mistaken.

Comment: *No*, OP asks for $\inf$ and $\sup$ (not $\min$ and $\max)$ for $K$ as given, **and** "for $\subseteq$ from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$". Not "for $\subseteq$ from $K$", and not just ""for $\subseteq$". I take this to mean, find $\inf$ and $\sup$ in the lattice $(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \subseteq)$.

Comment: @BrianO: While I understand your point of view, the OP asks: "what is the infimum and supremum *from $K$*", so I'll take this literally.

Comment: @AlexM. Yeah, *from* $K$, not *in* $K$. Assuming that they have to be in $K$ is a bit silly or vacuous, as they don't exist. But it's also silly that we should have to speculate :) I understand your point of view too. The question could be better-written. Perhaps OP can enlighten us.